# How to get sender's email address if user is an active directory user?

Tags: outlook, sender

I am using get_SenderEmailAddress() of Outlook::_MailItem object to get sender's email address. But if user is an active directory user, then recipientitem.address looks like this: **/o=organizationg/ou=exchange administrative group /cn=recipients/cn=xxxxxxxxxx**.

Is there any other way to get sender's email address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook VBA Mailitem property SenderEmailAddress not returning address correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746770/outlook-vba-mailitem-property-senderemailaddress-not-returning-address-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a perfectly valid email address of type `"EX"` (as opposed to "SMTP").

If you want the SMTP address, use `MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`. Be prepared to handle nulls and exceptions. 
But first check the `MailItems.SenderEmailType` property - if it is "SMTP", you can still use `SenderEmailAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to get the Sender Mail Address.

```
 private string GetSenderSMTPAddress(Outlook.MailItem mail)
    {
        try
        {
            string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =
                    @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"; if (mail == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
            if (mail.SenderEmailType == "EX")
            {
                Outlook.AddressEntry sender =
                    mail.Sender;
                if (sender != null)
                {
                    //Now we have an AddressEntry representing the Sender
                    if (sender.AddressEntryUserType ==
                        Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                        olExchangeUserAddressEntry
                        || sender.AddressEntryUserType ==
                        Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                        olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
                    {
                        //Use the ExchangeUser object PrimarySMTPAddress
                        Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser =
                            sender.GetExchangeUser();
                        if (exchUser != null)
                        {
                            return exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
                            PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) as string;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return mail.SenderEmailAddress;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```