# Remove Email addresses outside a specific Domain using Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

At work there is a VBA code that is used to reply to emails in outlook to save time typing out the generic response. it works perfectly fine however I am trying to change it so that if the email address is outside of the companies domain it gets removed from the recipients before being sent.

so short version:

- VBA to sent a replyall response
- However don't want to send it to emails outside of a singular domain

This is the Code that I have presently that doesn't work.

```
Sub testReply()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As MailItem

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set olReply = olItem.replyall

        For Each recipientAddress In olReply.Recipients
            If Not InStrRev(LCase(recipientAddress), "*@domain.com.au") Then
                recipientAddress.Delete
            End If
        Next
   
        olReply.HTMLBody = "Email response goes here" & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
    
        olReply.Display
      olReply.Send
    Next olItem
End Sub
```

This code removes all but one email address from the response which is not what I am aiming for.

For example if the recipients are name@domain.com, name1@domain.com, and person@outside.com I only want the reply to go to emails with @domain.com not @outside.com

Comment: `InStr` doesn't support wildcards.

Comment: `Debug.Print` will likely reveal addresses in Exchange format not SMTP format.

Comment: [SenderEmailAddress not returning address correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746770/outlook-vba-mailitem-property-senderemailaddress-not-returning-address-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

`InStr` (`InStrRev`) doesn't support wildcards `*`.

Try

`InStr(LCase(recipientAddress), "@domain.com.au")`

or

`LCase(recipientAddress) Like "*@domain.com.au"`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried both of these options and unfortuntely had the same result. It is removing all receipients but one

Comment: Would mind share what's the recipients list (without privacy leaking) ? And what's the exptected result?

Comment: unfortunately the recipients change per email that’s why I have been trying to base the response on the domain rather than individuals as I always want the response to go to people within that domain but if they are outside of that (IE a different company) I don’t want it to go to them. Makes it tricky :(

Comment: What's the logic to validate the email `within that domain`? You can keep a white-list if there are multiple domain.

Comment: The expected result is that it sends a reply with specific body text to all email addresses included in the received email excluding any emails addresses outside of the company

Comment: the issue is that not all emails need to receive the same treatment thats why I was hoping to make the determination by domain as the list of those in that domain is always changing

Comment: `It is removing all receipients but one` Which one is left? Which one(s) is accidently removed by code? Please share sample email.

Comment: Unfortuntely I cant give an example as who is left is different on each email and as much as I would like to provide an example I cant without company information going with it.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes a company address is an Exchange address.
Accommodates company addresses you may have saved in SMTP format.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub testReply()

    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim olReply As MailItem

    Dim ReplyRecipients As Recipients
    Dim i As Long
    Dim smtpEmailAddress As String
    
    For Each olItem In ActiveExplorer.selection
        
        If TypeOf olItem Is MailItem Then
        
            Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
            olReply.Display
            
            Set ReplyRecipients = olReply.Recipients
            
            Debug.Print ReplyRecipients.count
            
            For i = ReplyRecipients.count To 1 Step -1
                
                If ReplyRecipients(i).AddressEntry.Type = "EX" Then
                    
                    Debug.Print "Exchange address: " & ReplyRecipients(i).Address
                    
                    ' Assume an exchange address is a company address
                    smtpEmailAddress = ReplyRecipients(i).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                    Debug.Print "SMTP address: " & smtpEmailAddress
                    
                Else
                
                    If InStr(LCase(ReplyRecipients(i).Address), "@domain.com.au") = 0 Then
                        Debug.Print "Address: " & ReplyRecipients(i).Address
                        ReplyRecipients(i).Delete
                    End If
                    
                End If
                
            Next
        
            olReply.htmlbody = "Email response goes here" & vbCrLf & olReply.htmlbody
    
            olReply.Display
            'olReply.Send
        End If
    Next olItem
End Sub
```