# Script to run in outlook 2013 to export mail details to notepad

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to create an application that needs the sender information of an email in outlook to Send a new email with information processed in the application. I need to execute the application each time I get a mail with specific text in the subject. I can do this with the help of rules in outlook but I am not able to retrieve the Sender info from Outlook mail to pass it to my application. Is there any way possible to export this detail.My application is CSharp Console application that takes care of email sending.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read sender's email address from MS Outlook mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854047/read-senders-email-address-from-ms-outlook-mail)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your background as a developer, it's hard to say, but **as I have no knowledge of creating Office plugins** and then the need to install in each person outlook `n` as you have Outlook in your machines (plus, it would only work in your computer, not if you open the email in a mobile)...

**I would** then, **approach the problem in another way**:

1. signup for a free email account like [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com) or [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com)
2. create a normal rule that would forward the email with the subject to that new email address you just created
3. Now, even with `curl` commands or any other language tool you can query that mailbox, extract what you want, send the file to whatever you need and delete the mail once processed